# Simplifying Multiple Line Array

Tags: java, arrays

I am still new to Java and was wondering is there a way to cut my array down to utilize a remainder operator to start a new line when 5 goes into a number and there is not thing left over? I have been trying to figure this out for since this morning and don't seem to be gaining any progress. Thank you for your help in advance.

```
    public class arrayTest {

        public static void main(String args[]) { 
            final int ARRAY_LENGTH = 25;           // number of ints 
            int array[] = new int[ ARRAY_LENGTH ]; // calculate value for each array element 

            for (int counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++ ) 
                System.out.printf("%d, ", counter); 
            for (int counter = 5; counter < 6; counter++ ) 
                System.out.printf("%d\n", counter);
            for (int counter = 6; counter < 10; counter++ ) 
                System.out.printf("%d, ", counter);
            for (int counter = 10; counter < 11; counter++ ) 
                System.out.printf("%d\n", counter);
            for (int counter = 11; counter < 15; counter++ ) 
                System.out.printf("%d, ", counter);
            for (int counter = 15; counter < 16; counter++ ) 
                System.out.printf("%d\n", counter);
            for (int counter = 16; counter < 20; counter++ ) 
                System.out.printf("%d, ", counter);
            for (int counter = 20; counter < 21; counter++ ) 
                System.out.printf("%d\n", counter);
            for (int counter = 21; counter < 25; counter++ ) 
                System.out.printf("%d, ", counter);
            for (int counter = 25; counter < 26; counter++ ) 
                System.out.printf("%d\n", counter);
        } 

    }
```

Comment: What...are you trying to do?  And why aren't you using just one loop to do it with?

Comment: Use one loop and the `modulo` operator `%`

Comment: As a side note: class names in Java by convention should start with upper case letter. Read this: [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
public class arrayTest
{

public static void main( String args[] )
{
  final int ARRAY_LENGTH = 25; // number of ints 
  int array[] = new int[ ARRAY_LENGTH ];// calculate value for each array element 
  for (int counter = 0; counter < array.length; counter++ ) {
    System.out.printf("%d, ", counter); 
    if (counter%5 == 4) {
    System.out.printf("\n"); // System.out.println() also works
    }
  }
}

}
```

Comment: Yes, because his first for iterates 6 times (I assumed that's a bug) and he doesn't display final comma (easy to implement once he understands how if and remainder work). I didn't want to complicate the example.

Answer (score 0):

Use this after you initialize your array

```
for(int i=0; i<ARRAY_LENGTH;i+=5){
   for(int counter=i;counter<i+5;counter++){
      array[counter]=counter;
      System.out.print(counter);
   }
   System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Comment: This code prints only numbers which divided by 5 give remainder 0, unless I've misunderstood his intentions, this is different to OP's original output.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use one loop as follows:

```
final int ARRAY_LENGTH = 25;
int[] array = new int[ARRAY_LENGTH];
for(int i = 1; i <= ARRAY_LENGTH; i++){
    array[i - 1] = i % 5;
    System.out.println(i % 5);
```

Comment: This code inserts new line on each iteration, that is not what OP wanted. Also, you are missing a closing bracket at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your for loops with this (same output as your program), comments in code:

```
public class arrayTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) { 
        final int ARRAY_LENGTH = 25;           // number of ints 
        int array[] = new int[ ARRAY_LENGTH ]; // calculate value for each array element 

        for (int counter = 0; counter < ARRAY_LENGTH; counter++ ) {
            array[counter] = counter;
            System.out.printf("%d, ", counter);

            //skip 0, then if current number modulo 5 is zero (no remainder)
            //insert new line
            if (counter > 0  && counter % 5 == 0) System.out.println();
        }
        //to add 25 at the end, as in your code, you can do this:
        //this is because our loop starts at 0 and goes until 24
        System.out.println(ARRAY_LENGTH);
    } 
}
```